# Telescope nvim not displaying results

Tags: lua, neovim, telescope.nvim

I am trying to set up telescope with nvim and ubuntu 22.04 is windows wsl (windows 10 on an older dell laptop). I installed it using packer and it seems to install just fine and I can do `<leader>ff` and it pops up just fine but doesn't display anything. I don't really use nvim a lot that so idk what is going on.

[image: Screenshot of Telescope]

I just have the default config. So here is my packer config at `.config/nvim/lua/plugins/init.lua`

```
return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'

    use {
  'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.1',
    -- or                            , branch = '0.1.x',
    requires = { {'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'} }
    }

end)
```

And here is my `.config/nvim/init.lua` file:

```
require('plugins')

vim.o.number = true
vim.o.autoindent = true
vim.o.tabstop = 2
vim.o.shiftwidth = 2
vim.o.mouse = 'a'

vim.g.mapleader = ' '
-- vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ff', vim.cmd.Ex)


-- Enable copy and paste from clipboard
if vim.fn.has("wsl") == 1 then 
    vim.g.clipboard = {
        name = 'WslClipboard',
        copy = {
            ['+'] = 'clip.exe',
            ['*'] = 'clip.exe',
        },
        paste = {
            ['+'] = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
            ['*'] = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
        },
        cache_enabled = 0
    }
end

-- Set up Telescope keybindings
local builtin = require('telescope.builtin')
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ff', builtin.find_files, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fb', builtin.buffers, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fh', builtin.help_tags, {})
```

This is all of the nvim configuration I have so not really sure what is going on.

Comment: You may find better answers on https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Run `:checkhealth telescope` to know what is missing and install it.

https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim#checkhealth

Comment: Thanks, in my case I was missing ripgrep: `sudo apt install ripgrep`